# Colour correction of Photoshop LUT filter using CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, pixel, core-image

Using photoshop to create LUT filter and use iOS CIFilter to read the LUT image, filter image created by iOS is not corresponding to the filer image created by photoshop.

How can I trace the issue?
[image]

This is the original image
[image]

This is the image with filter I created from photoshop
[image]

This is the image with filter I created from iPhone
[image]

This is the LUT image I am using
[image]

Comment: I dont use **CIFilter** but your image seems to be a difference between how Photoshop and iOS convert the image to greyscale (each channel of red, green, blue will show as various levels of grey). Also your PhotoShop image is in **PNG** (4 channels) but your iOS image is in **JPG** (3 channels). Keep one format only (try JPG) for Original vs PShop vs iOS comparison.

Answer (score 0):

please Try This its work for me

```
public class LUTsHelper {

public static func applyLUTsFilter(lutImage: String, dimension: Int, colorSpace: CGColorSpace) -> CIFilter? {

    guard let image = UIImage(named: lutImage) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let bitmap = createBitmap(image: cgImage, colorSpace: colorSpace) else {
        return nil
    }

    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    let rowNum = width / dimension
    let columnNum = height / dimension

    let dataSize = dimension * dimension * dimension * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4

    var array = Array<Float>(repeating: 0, count: dataSize)

    var bitmapOffest: Int = 0
    var z: Int = 0

    for _ in stride(from: 0, to: rowNum, by: 1) {
        for y in stride(from: 0, to: dimension, by: 1) {
            let tmp = z
            for _ in stride(from: 0, to: columnNum, by: 1) {
                for x in stride(from: 0, to: dimension, by: 1) {

                    let dataOffset = (z * dimension * dimension + y * dimension + x) * 4

                    let position = bitmap
                        .advanced(by: bitmapOffest)

                    array[dataOffset + 0] = Float(position
                        .advanced(by: 0)
                        .pointee) / 255

                    array[dataOffset + 1] = Float(position
                        .advanced(by: 1)
                        .pointee) / 255

                    array[dataOffset + 2] = Float(position
                        .advanced(by: 2)
                        .pointee) / 255

                    array[dataOffset + 3] = Float(position
                        .advanced(by: 3)
                        .pointee) / 255

                    bitmapOffest += 4

                }
                z += 1
            }
            z = tmp
        }
        z += columnNum
    }

    free(bitmap)

    let data = Data.init(bytes: array, count: dataSize)

    guard
    let cubeFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCubeWithColorSpace")
    else {
        return nil
    }

    cubeFilter.setValue(dimension, forKey: "inputCubeDimension")
    cubeFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputCubeData")
    cubeFilter.setValue(colorSpace, forKey: "inputColorSpace")

    return cubeFilter

}

private static func createBitmap(image: CGImage, colorSpace: CGColorSpace) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>? {

    let width = image.width
    let height = image.height

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerRow = width * 4

    let bitmapSize = bytesPerRow * height

    guard let data = malloc(bitmapSize) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let context = CGContext(
        data: data,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
        bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
        space: colorSpace,
        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue,
        releaseCallback: nil,
        releaseInfo: nil) else {
            return nil
    }

    context.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    return data.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: bitmapSize)
}}
```

now us this class

```
        let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpace.init(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB) ?? CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let lutFilter = LUTsHelper.applyLUTsFilter(lutImage: "demo.png", dimension: 64, colorSpace: colorSpace)
        lutFilter?.setValue(outputImage, forKey: "inputImage")

        let lutOutputImage = lutFilter?.outputImage

        if let output = lutOutputImage {
            outputImage = output
        }
```